# reusing dialog box

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources

I have a dialog box from an old program that I would like to reuse, but I can't find an easy way to import/export it.

I'm pretty sure the .rc file contains all the sizing/spacing info, but if I try to import it, a 'Custom Resource' option appears.

Is it best to generate a new .rc file, and then edit it directly (ie, copy and paste the values from the old .rc file)? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open source and destination .rc files in Visual Studio using File - Open function (without loading the project). Now it is possible to drag-and-drop resources between two .rc files, or use Copy-Paste. Visual Studio updates also resource.h file when resource is pasted into .rc file. More details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5axa064.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829437

Answer (score 0):

I would just copy/paste the textual definition.

Answer (score 0):

I find very easy to use some resource editors like ResEdit, so you don't need to bother about such things.